# System.IO.FileLoadException from .msi but not when starting service manually

Tags: c#, wix

I've been fooling with this for days and am now reaching out for help. I have an .msi file built using WiX. It is fairly simply in that it copies a few files to a directory and installs & runs a service. The service (in my example) does nothing but call Environment.Exit(0) in the thread started by OnStart. As soon as that thread fires up I get the FileLoadException. I've tried with both x32 and x64 configurations. I've tried Fuslogvw, but it's always empty. I don't know what else to do to get it to work. I'll gladly supply my .xml (for the .msi) and my C# program that's the Service if anyone cares to look at them.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Under what account is this service installed to startup?

Comment: The default account, which is supposed to be the LocalSystem account. I did try changing it to be my own account, but I got the same error either way. (I am in the Administrators group.)

Comment: Process Monitor is your friend (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).  Do a filter on your process and look for the failures related to accessing a file.

Comment: Good idea Andy. I'll try to see what's going on and report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I'm not *sure* why it's working, but my guess is because I am copying out a required .dll from the .msi that I hadn't been copying before. (The .dll was already out there, so I didn't think I needed the .msi to copy it again.) My guess is that the .msi somehow assigns a version or something to all the files its responsible for, and since the .dll that was already out there wasn't versioned per the .msi it failed when it tried to run the thread that used that .dll. Reasonable guess?

Comment: Managed code references depend (among other things) on AssemblyVersion, which MSI doesn't care about - it uses file versions. It's possible your build of the dependent assemblies has a * somewhere in the AssemblyVersion, so it could be out of step with what the service expects to link to. A dependency in the GAC isn't available until after StartService, but all the dlls are in the app folder, yes? Or maybe it's just that the required assembly wasn't in the final MSI for some reason, maybe that's all there is to it.